# Navigation drawer in Android Studio 2.2.2 with SDK 24 does not support API 19

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-4.4-kitkat, android-studio-2.2

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 and Android SDK 24 in my project. When I install my app in KitKat 4.4.2, the app runs correctly - except when I click on a button that opens activity within the navigation drawer. Doing this crashes the app.

This is gradle(module:app)when sdktoolbuildversion is 19.1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '19.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sudan.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and the message is:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

How can I configure my app to run in API 19?

Comment: First, don't change your `buildToolsVersion` to 19. Keep it on 24. Second, if your `minSdkVersion` is 15, just set your compile and target versions to at least 27. Third, your "crash" log isn't a crash log. It's a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest that always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager, before doing this, click `Help-Check for Updates` to get latest android studio and plugin version.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '19.1' //comment or delete this line
                         //If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher
                         //your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sudan.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

If you dont' want to above step, try this:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.2.1' //modify this


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1' //same as appcompat-v7
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried the second solution and succeeded with me